# Change varchar to bigint

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Currently I have a package that loads a table. However, I am wanting to change the productnumber field to a bigint that is currently a varchar. I also want to create a new column for the old productnumbers. so currently it looks like this:

ProductNumber: 1827493849, PN19379247

As you can see the product number has nonnumeric in them which is why I want a column to store the old numbers such as they are currently. but my goal is to create a column that will store these two numbers and more where it takes the leading PN off. Can someone please give examples to how this is done. Currently I have created a new table with ProductNumber as bigint  and OldNumer as varchar and the table is empty. I want it to be able to store the account numbers as is under OldNumber and then insert them into the other column taking the leading PN off. Which the PN must be taken off before inserting to the ProductNumber column because it is a bigint. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your value always 2 values, delimited with a comma, with the second always prefixed with `'PN'`?

Comment: @Larnu I have many values in that column that was just example of values I am viewing currently. I have some that are numeric and some with a leading PN.

Comment: So them a single row can contain more than 2 delimited values? More sample data would be really useful here; especially if you have a varying number of values. Why are you storing delimited values in the first place though? You really need to rethink your design if so.

Comment: @Larnu Only one row can have one value I use a comma to seperate the two meaning one was in one row and the other was in another row

Comment: PN1827382739
182789374934
394759847304
PN9375495793

Comment: Imagine these four having their own row is what I am currently viewing

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend a `bigint` for this.  Instead, use a `numeric` of the appropriate length.

If you want to convert a string by removing the first two characters, you can use `stuff()`:

```
select try_convert(numeric(20), stuff(productnumber, 1, 2, ''))
```

If you don't know where the number begins, then look for it using `patindex()`:

```
select try_convert(numeric(20), stuff(productnumber, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%', productnumber) - 1, ''))
```